# Dynamically scaling websites based on usage pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, scalability

I have to architect and design a web application which needs a dynamic scaling solutions. It needs to support a a few million requests during mornings (from approx. 10 AM to 12 AM), with only a few thousand requests during the rest of the day.

Same way, during a peek season or holiday seasons i should be able to support peaks of up to several million requests per hour.

I dont want to scale up or scale out statically, as the usage pattern of the site differs from time to time, so I'm looking into dynamic scaling.

What are some of the approaches to this problem? I am looking for best practices and experience report (public and private clouds).

Comment: Design of systems is generally outside of scope of SO... There is not too many options - you either have your own capacity or get it from somewhere ("cloud"). You seem not to have own reserves, so it leaves you with picking cloud provider you like... (Side note: just "millions" in not really good measurement of load - is it request/per second OR total users OR something else?)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov total users load

Comment: Maybe you could look into Amazon's elastic cloud services? I think you can get virtual windows machine there.